# Create a java List of objects over another List with realtime conversion

Tags: java, oop

So, i need like this:

```
public class ContainerList implements List<String>{
  private final List<Integer> _list;
  
  public ContainerList(List<Integer> listInt){
    _list = listInt;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return _list.size();
  }

  @Override
  public String get(int index) {
    // some convertation, it is the main objective
    return Integer.toString(_list.get(index));
  }

  ... // so much overrides!!
}
```

I need to create new list as container of another list with realtime convertion. I cannot create normal ArrayList or doing like this

```
List<String> listStr =
  listInt.stream().map(i -> Integer.toString(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

because that listInt can be changed later and that changes should be reflected in listStr inmediatly. I can create a custom universal List like ContainerList<T>, but is not so fast.
So, the cuestion is: "Exist any elegant solution for doing it without using a lib or can you suggest a good library?"

Comment: Do you need only the option to stream the list elements?

Comment: Nop, i dont need a stream. As result, i need a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend an [`AbstractList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html) like this

```
public class TransformedList<S, E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private List<S> sourceElements;
    private Function<S, E> transformer;

    public TransformedList(List<S> sourceElements, Function<S, E> transformer) {
        this.sourceElements = sourceElements;
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return sourceElements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        S sourceElement = sourceElements.get(index);
        return transformer.apply(sourceElement);
    }
}
```

You can then use like this

```
List<String> numberStrings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> intList =  new TransformedList<>(numberStrings, Integer::parseInt);
```

Since the `TransformedList` is just a kind of view on the source list it, it will change whenever the source list changes.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("hello");
List<String> upperCaseList = new TransformedList<>(strings, String::toUpperCase);

System.out.println(upperCaseList.get(0));

strings.set(0, "world");

System.out.printlan(upperCaseList.get(0));
```

will output:

```
HELLO
WORLD
```

An `AbstractList` is readonly and will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when you invoke a mutator method like `clear`, `remove`, `add` or `set`.

If you want to make it mutable override:

- set(int, Object)
- add(int, Object)
- remove(int)

Comment: Thx, this solution is more acceptable for my purposes due the project lightweight and mutability control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Guava's [`Lists.transform`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function-).

> Returns a list that applies function to each element of `fromList`. The returned list is a transformed view of `fromList`; changes to `fromList` will be reflected in the returned list and vice versa.

```
List<String> listStr = Lists.transform(listInt, Object::toString);
```

Comment: Thx, is a elegant solution, but for my purposes the listStr should preferably be readonly.

Comment: @pro100kryto You can wrap it in `Collections.unmodifiableList` if you want that complete immutability.